# MVC3- How to link the data from different controller's views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i've been on this for days and its givin me quite a headache...

I have a client model containing client details,  i then have an address model containing different addresses for clients. I want to display the (CRUD) table under each client's details when i click on the details link in the (CRUD) table for the client. How do i go about doing that?

Comment: Use partial views, you can use ajaxcalls or normal calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a composite view model when displaying the client details or use AJAX to load the addresses when the client's details are displayed.  I'd probably go with the former since the two are closely related and it seems like overkill to have a controller or action for just addresses (unless you would ever display them on their own without the other information).

```
 public class ClientDetailsModel
 {
      public ClientDetails Details { get; set; }
      public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
 }


 public ActionResult Details( int id )
 {
       var client = this.ClientRepository.GetByID( id );
       var addresses = this.ClientRepository.GetAddressesForClient( client );
       return View( new ClientDetailsModel { Details = client, Addresses = addresses } );
 }
```

That's similar to what I would do, though it's more likely that I'd extract only the relevant properties and fill in a flat model class for each of the client/address parts rather than use the actual entity from the DB.  AutoMapper can be a big help with this.

Once in the view you can abstract the address display into a partial view and render it for each address if you need to reuse the code.

```
  ... display client details...

  @foreach (var address in Model.Addresses)
  {
       @Html.Partial( "_Address", address )
  }
```

Comment: I've been reading on viewmodels andajax but i just dont get it... i'm very new to this, can you please provide me with a step by step process as to how i can go about doing it?

Comment: @Cutie the above isn't AJAX.  You simply construct a separate class for the model sent to the view using data from your entities. The view is typed to this model, not your entity model. This model contains data from multiple entities (I'm using them directly in this example, but in practice I would probably flatten the view class by replicating the properties needed and just fill them in).

Comment: Oh.. The above Details method is implemented in the Clientcontroller right? what do i put in the getById() and getAddressForClient(), and where do i implement them?

Comment: @Cutie yes on the controller.  Those methods would be on your data context or repository class -- however you are getting the data from the DB.  It was just a sample to show how the entities would map into the view model.  I use repositories, but I had no idea how you were doing it.

Comment: k..dont still quite get it but thank u very much for ur help... ireally appreciate it